# Why is reference type variable behaves like value type variable

Tags: c#, .net, value-type, reference-type

So, I have a reference type which is Weapon:

```
class Weapon
{
    //Some properties that are both value type and reference type
}
```

And I have another class to hold an array of weapons and fire an event when the current weapon changes:

```
class WeaponManager
{
    Weapon[] weapons;
    Weapon currentWeapon;

    Weapon CurrentWeapon
    {
       get => currentWeapon;
       set
       {
           Weapon oldWeapon = currentWeapon;
           currentWeapon = value;
           OnWeaponChanged?.Invoke(oldWeapon, currentWeapon);
       }
    }
}
```

I declare the oldWeapon variable and assign it to currentWeapon in order to hold the data. My question is that I believe since the Weapon is a reference type, when I reassign currentWeapon, oldWeapon should also change. But for some reason assignements I make to currentWeapon variable doesn't effect the oldWeapon. Is there some sort of thing going around that I'm not aware of or did I misunderstand something?

Note: Weapon class is deriving from another class which has at least one string in it but I'm not sure if that's the issue.

Comment: "..when I reassign currentWeapon, oldWeapon should also change". Nope. Also, the code does not show any "changes I make to currentWeapon variable" so it's hard to really explain the not-shown behavior.

Comment: Could you explain why? By changes I make to currentWeapon variable, I meant things like reassigning currentWeapon in the setter. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Variables (names) are *idependent* of the objects (values which can often be modified) that they refer to / name. Modifying an object modifies that object, regardless of the name used to resolve the object. In this case no *modification* of an object is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something going on that you're not misunderstanding. Each reference you establish to an object in memory is its own reference, it is not a reference to another reference to the object (it is not a chain)

```
//if you do
currentWeapon = "a sword"
oldWeapon = currentWeapon

//then you have this
oldWeapon --> "a sword" <-- currentWeapon

//you do not have this
oldWeapon  --> currentWeapon --> "a sword"


//if you then do this
currentWeapon = "a gun"

//then you have this
oldWeapon --> "a sword"      currentWeapon --> "a gun"

//you do not have this
oldWeapon  --> currentWeapon --> "a gun"
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that it was a chain-like structure.